# How can I count a specific element in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

In a dataframe like below

```
          equips
0       bags, balls 
1        glasses
2    shoes, caps, bags
3          NaN
4     spoons, balls
```

I want to count the numbers of comma and make another column like below

```
          equips              the number of comma
0       bags, balls                    1
1        glasses                       0
2    shoes, caps, bags                 2
3          NaN                         0
4     spoons, balls                    1
```

Please, I need your help..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.count` method as follows:

```
df['the number of comma'] = df['equips'].str.count(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple list comprehension like so:

```
df['the number of comma'] = [i.count(',') for i in df['equips']]
```